# Parent view model that contains both models

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have two separate child models which I have created and I want to be able to create a parent model which would allow me to use both child models in one View.

The problem that I am running into is that I keep getting errors from my View which is informing me that Parent Model isn't accessing the variable.
"MainPageModel does not contain a defintion..."

*My end goal from this is to be able to have a form that uses input and has the ability to upload an image all in one model. This creates a simple profile with an image. On submission, you would be brought to another View, with what your profile would look like.*

**MODEL 1:**

```
namespace Profile.Models
{
    public class Profiler
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Model 2:**

```
namespace Profile.Models
{
    public interface IFormFile
    {
        string ContentType { get; }
        string ContentDisposition { get; }
        IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; }
        long Length { get; }
        string Name { get; }
        string FileName { get; }
        Stream OpenReadStream();
        void CopyTo(Stream target);
        Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**Parent Model:**

```
namespace Profile.Models
{
    public class MainPageModel
    {
        public Profiler Profiler { get; set; }
        public IFormFile IFormFile { get; set; }

        public MainPageModel(Profiler Profiler)
        {
            Profiler = Profiler;
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Profile.Models.MainPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profiler";
}
<h2>Create your Profile using the form below</h2>
<h3>On Submission, your profile will be created for you to see.</h3>

<form asp-action="Profiler" >
    <label asp-for="FName"></label>
    <input asp-for="FName" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="Address"></label>
    <input asp-for="Address" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="BirthDate"></label>
    <input asp-for="BirthDate" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="PhoneNumber"></label>
    <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="Comments"></label>
    <input asp-for="Comments" /> <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**HomeController:**

```
public IActionResult Profiler([Bind("FName,Address,BirthDate,PhoneNumber,Comments")] Profiler Profiles)
    {
        return View(new MainPageModel (Profiles));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add parameter constructor to `MainPageModel`

```
namespace Profile.Models
{
    public class MainPageModel
    {
        public MainPageModel () {}

        public MainPageModel(Profiler profiler)
        {
            Profiler = profiler;
        }

        public Profiler Profiler { get; set; }

        public IFormFile Image{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

then add `Profile` prefix to inputs name in profile form and change file input name to `Image`:

```
@model Profile.Models.MainPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profiler";
}
<h2>Create your Profile using the form below</h2>
<h3>On Submission, your profile will be created for you to see.</h3>

<form asp-action="Profiler" method="post">
    <label asp-for="Profile.FName"></label>
    <input asp-for="Profile.FName" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="Profile.Address"></label>
    <input asp-for="Profile.Address" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="Profile.BirthDate"></label>
    <input asp-for="Profile.BirthDate" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="Profile.PhoneNumber"></label>
    <input asp-for="Profile.PhoneNumber" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="Profile.Comments"></label>
    <input asp-for="Profile.Comments" /> <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form asp-action="Profiler" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="Image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Profiler()
{
    return View(new MainPageModel(profile));
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Profiler(MainPageModel viewModel)
{
    if(viewModel.Profile != null )
    {
        // Save profile
    }
    else if(viewModel.Image != null)
    {
        // Save image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, why do you have an interface for `IFormFile`? There is *already* such an interface built-in to ASP.NET Core. At the least, it's redundant and unnecessary, and at the most you're going to end up causing conflicts. Get rid of it, and use the built-in `IFormFile`.

Then, your action is accepting only a `Profiler` instance. Your action needs to accept the same view model you're passing to your view or you're going to end up with all kinds of problems. In other words, if you want a combined view model like this, then you need to post that as well.

However, you don't need that at all if you actually set this up properly in the first place. First, you should *never* bind to an entity directly. An entity class is and should be a simple DTO class, and should be designed only with an eye to the needs of the database, since that's its purpose. The view has different concerns and needs, which are totally inappropriate to be handled by your entity class. This is the purpose of view models, so you should have one like `ProfilerViewModel`. Your `Profiler` entity should have some way of persisting your file uploads, whether that be `byte[]` properties or simple string properties that merely point to URL or file path where the uploaded file can be found. Your view model, meanwhile, would have your `IFormFile` property. When mapping from your view model to your entity, you would then save the uploaded file and fill the appropriate propert(ies) on your entity.

This also allows you to get rid of the god-forsaken `Bind` attribute, which should really never be used. Seriously, it's horrible in every facet. It only exists to pave over the glaring security vulnerability caused by using entities directly, instead of actually encouraging developers to design their applications correctly in the first place.

With your action accepting a correct view model, you can then fix the issue of having two separate forms on the page, which is going to severely piss your users off, since submitting the first form will not post any uploaded files and submitting the second form will not post any profile changes they made. Basically, either way, you're discarding user input. Move the file input into the first form and get rid of the second. And, of course, bring the `enctype` attribute over as well.

Finally, you're allowing multiple files to be uploaded, but all you have is a property that accepts a single `IFormFile`. You need a `List<IFormFile>`.

Long and short:

```
public class ProfilerViewModel
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Profiler(ProfilerViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var profile = new Profiler
        {
            FName = model.FName,
            Address = model.Address,
            BirthDate = model.BirthDate,
            PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber
            Comments = model.Comments
        };

        foreach (var file in model.Files)
        {
            // handle your file uploads
        }

        db.Profiles.Add(profile);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Somewhere");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

And in your view:

```
@model Profile.Models.ProfilerViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profiler";
}
<h2>Create your Profile using the form below</h2>
<h3>On Submission, your profile will be created for you to see.</h3>

<form asp-action="Profiler" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label asp-for="FName"></label>
    <input asp-for="FName" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="Address"></label>
    <input asp-for="Address" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="BirthDate"></label>
    <input asp-for="BirthDate" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="PhoneNumber"></label>
    <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" /> <br /><br />
    <label asp-for="Comments"></label>
    <input asp-for="Comments" /> <br /><br />
    <input asp-for="Files" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then, everything should work just fine.